# Windows C# Font Size calcs

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, fonts

I was wondering what was causing the following issue: If I create a new font, of a specified size in points, then measure a string - in points again, I get two different values?

i.e.

```
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 36, GraphicsUnit.Point);

        Graphics g =  CreateGraphics();

        g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Point;

        string str = "hello";

        SizeF size = g.MeasureString(str, font);
```

size.height == 44 as opposed to 36 which is the specified PT size of the font!!

Whats going on??!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx). Extra space might be the reason for different sizes

> The MeasureString method is designed for use with individual strings
>   and includes a small amount of extra space before and after the string
>   to allow for overhanging glyphs

Answer (score 1):

MeasureString pads the returned rect to allow for overhanging and underhanging characters. This shows a typical rect returned by MeasureString:

[image]

So naturally the returned height will be larger than the specified size of the font in points.

Comment: @iraSenthil: then why am I still at 0 here? :)